# Determine SQL Statement type in OCCI

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, occi

I am writing a generic database handling layer for Oracle using Oracle C++ Call Interface (OCCI). It must accept SQL strings provided by other parts of the application (with no indication of what type of statement it is) and should then check that the type of statement is allowed for the calling part of the application and if so, execute it on behalf of the caller.

However, I cannot find an efficient way to get the SQL statement type (select, update, delete etc) from the OCCI statement I create based on the provided SQL string.

In OCI it is possible to get this information by calling `OCIAttrGet()` on the OCI Statement Handle, passing `OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE` to the `attrtype` parameter, but I cannot find any equivalent function in OCCI.

I *can* get the OCI Statement Handle from the OCCI Statement by calling `getOCIStatement()`, but so far the attempts to get the statement type attribute from this OCI Statement Handle has failed:

```
  OCIStmt *ociStmt = sqlstmt->getOCIStatement();
  ub2 statementType = OCI_STMT_UNKNOWN;
  OCIError *errhp = 0;

  sword result = OCIAttrGet(ociStmt, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, &statementType, 0, OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE, errhp);
```

When I run the above I get `result = -2` and no changes in `statementType`

In any case I think this approach is rather backwards, and would much rather operate cleanly with OCCI.

Does anyone know how to determine the SQL statement type of a prepared OCCI Statement (short of parsing the raw sql string, which is neither efficient nor safe)?

Comment: I had some problems with this too - when using pure OCI. Maybe this link will help you. Some constants must be observed. They are not documented by Oracle. See: https://sourceforge.net/p/tora/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tora/extlibs/trotl/src/trotl_stat.cpp#l182

Comment: maybe you should also allocate an error handle and then (possibly) you will get some more information from it. PS: I think OCCI is not the best C++ library for OCI.

Comment: Do you need to do this so you know what kind of statement you will be executing?  If that is the reason there is an plain `execute()` function that you can run that will run a non returning or returning sql statement.  The `execute()` function returns a `Status` that you can capture and check to see if there is data that was returned or not.

Comment: I also need to do it to check e.g. that the type of SQL statement is legal for the caller to make. Some parts of the application are only allowed to get select statements processed, and in some cases certain invariants must hold if the application provides an insert statement, and so on. So the `execute()` function is just not enough for my needs.